# implement setInterval function for autoplay on simple slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to **add an autoplay feature that loops by default to** this **simple image carousel** that has captions. My first attempt was just adding what was included for click function under on dom ready as well.. this didn't work. *Note I still need the navigation buttons to remain working as well.*

**jQuery**:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img-wrap .slideZ:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.nextbox').click(function() {
        $('.captionZ').fadeIn();
        $('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeOut("slow").next().fadeIn("slow").end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
    });
    $('.prevbox').click(function() {
        $('.captionZ').fadeIn();
        $('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeOut();
        $('.img-wrap .slideZ:last-child').prependTo('.img-wrap').fadeOut();
        $('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeIn();
     });
    });
```

**Mark-Up**:

```
<div class="paginateyo">
            <div class="prevbox">
            <img src="images/prev_arrow.jpg" id="prv" alt="Previous"/>
            <span class="prvp">previous</span>
            </div>
            /
            <div class="nextbox">
            <span class="nxtp">next</span>
            <img src="images/next_arrow.jpg" id="nxt" alt="Next"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>  

        <div id="img-grp-wrap">
            <div class="img-wrap">
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image2.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image3.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">cccccccccccccccc
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image4.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">dddddddddddddddd
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image5.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image6.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">fffffffffffffffff
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image7.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">gggggggggggggggggg
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
function interval(){
    function(){
     $('.captionZ').fadeIn();
     $('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeOut("slow").next().fadeIn("slow").end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
}    
var t = setInterval(interval) ;
```

If you want it to move on to the "next" image. Depending on how you want it set up, you could also make it so that `onclick` makes it reset the `setInterval()` function by removing the interval with `window.clearInterval(interval)` then creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks, finally got this after some tinkering.. Can't get the clear interval to work though :(